# adding values in cursor data

Tags: android, database, listview

i am developing an application and i need to put times of my alarm in a listview like that

- 12:45
- 13:11

my problem is and i know why is like that

that i get only one colmun like that

- 45
- 11

i want to get all the row from database not only one column item , how can i get all the row from database ? is there any easy solution?

package radiofm.arabel;

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";

    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "people_table";
    private static final String COL1 = "_id";
    private static final String COL2 = "Hour";
    private static final String COL3 = "Symbol";
    private static final String COL4 = "Minutes";



    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 1);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +

                COL1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +

                COL2 + " TEXT, " +

                COL3 + " TEXT, " +

                COL4 + " TEXT "  +

                ");";

        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean addData(String item1,String item2,String item3) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL2, item1);
        contentValues.put(COL3, item2);
        contentValues.put(COL4, item3);

        Log.d(TAG, "addData: Adding " + item1 + " to " + TABLE_NAME);


        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        //if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }


    public Cursor getListContents(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT Hour, Symbol, Minutes FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        return data;
    }


}
```

> Blockquote

```
    package radiofm.arabel;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Add_Alarm extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listalarm;
    DatabaseHelper myDB;

    Button button1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add__alarm);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        listalarm =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listalarm);

        myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);


        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addalarm);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent Intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Alarm.class);
                view.getContext().startActivity(Intent);}
        });


        //populate an ArrayList<String> from the database and then view it
        ArrayList<String> theList = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor data = myDB.getListContents();
        if(data.getCount() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(this, "There are no contents in this list!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            while(data.moveToNext()){
                theList.add(data.getString(2));
                ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,theList);
                listalarm.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            }
        }

    }




}
```

Comment: You should use a `CursorAdapter` instead of a `ListAdapter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably missed the `Hour` column from database :

change:

```
if(data.getCount() == 0){
        Toast.makeText(this, "There are no contents in this list!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        while(data.moveToNext()){
            theList.add(data.getString(2));
            ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,theList);
            listalarm.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }
    }
```

to:

```
  if(data.getCount() == 0){
        Toast.makeText(this, "There are no contents in this list!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        while(data.moveToNext()){
           theList.add(data.getString(0) + ":" + data.getString(2));

        }
        ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,theList);
        listalarm.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: fetching colmn value like  theList.add(data.getString(0) + ":" + data.getString(2)); is not good practice to fetch colomn try to suggest this
String col2_value=data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(COL2));

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh i dont know what are you talking about ?. I posted an answer. i re-read it. i found an modification. i edited my answer ? how is that plagiarism ?

Answer (score 2):

```
theList.add(data.getString(2));
```

Here you are getting the data from column index 2 and putting it into your list. This column appears to be the minutes. **If you want the hour as well, you have to get it from the `Cursor`.** Remember that a computer does only what you tell it to do.

Alternatively, you could use a `CursorAdapter`. Most likely you will need to create a custom adapter class yourself in order to get the values from the cursor and display them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try fetching like this from cursor and use accordingly...

```
String col1_value=data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(COL1));
String col2_value=data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(COL2));
String col3_value=data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(COL3));
```

And also notify your adapter after adding all values in list like that...

```
 Cursor data = myDB.getListContents();
        if(data.getCount() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(this, "There are no contents in this list!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            while(data.moveToNext()){
                theList.add(data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(COL2)));

            }
 ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,theList);
                listalarm.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }
```